# Remove blanks at ends of DataVisualization chart x axis

Tags: mschart

I am using Microsoft's DataVisualization.Charting.Chart, and I have integer values along the X axis, using line-style graphs.  However, the chart is adding an extra blank item at the beginning and end of the x-axis, with no value labels to explain what they are.

How can I remove these empty items and make the lines go right up to the ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Maximum` and `Minimum` properties in `ChartArea.AxisX`, e.g. :

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;   // if your minimum X = 0
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 100; // if your maximum X = 100
```

In this way, your chart area will show only the values between `Minimum` and `Maximum`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the IsMarginVisible property of the xaxis. I believe that will do the trick.

To test this, I changed one of my own charts to be a line chart and then set the value in the code:

```
ReactivityChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IsMarginVisible = False
```

Tell me if this is what you were hoping to get or if I have totally misunderstood the question:

(note that I do not have a high enough rep to post this image)

http://www.rectorsquid.com/chartmargintest.gif