# Blank spaces added to either side of X Axis values - Microsoft Charting

Tags: c#, charts

I'm using the C# Microsoft Charting Controls to generate this chart...

How can I remove the gaps on the left and right hand side so that the series actually start right on the 0 value y axis?? I don't have blank values in my series data, yet its adding these extra blank values on both the left and right hand sides...

E.g. I want the chart to stop at the "S" value on the right hand side, not have the blank extra value after it.

[image: Sample chart]

Answer (score 2):

Go to `ChartAreas -> Axes -> X axis -> IsMarginVisible -> false` in the properties box on your chart.

That's if you always want the margin to be hidden.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. In code behind, use this property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.ismarginvisible?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Ok this thread solved my problem, thanks!!

[Remove blanks at ends of DataVisualization chart x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060239/remove-blanks-at-ends-of-datavisualization-chart-x-axis)

This code works great:

```
 this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;   // if your minimum X = 0
 this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 100; // if your maximum X = 100
```

But Minimum = 1 and Maximum = 30 in my case...